# Do a consumable iOS product REQUIRE restore functionality?

Tags: ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

I am developing a game, and I want to submit it to the AppStore, but I don't know if this will be a cause for rejection:

Say a player can buy 100x arrows for 0.99$. Do I have to provide the user the ability to restore the unused arrows in order to not be rejected by the AppStore?

I really don't want to use a server to store the number of arrows the player has, as that would be off the budget.

Comment: Like go from arrows to $$? If so then no you don’t.

Comment: arrows will be only arrows... they will not be able to turn into cash again... @Josh: thanks a lot! you are my hero.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please check the answer below. P.S. Once you publish tell me the game. I'll be sure to try it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

In the requirements and guidelines for App Store Review (shown below) it does not say anything about a return mechanism. It does however say "you should make sure you have a restore mechanism for any restorable in-app purchases." What this means is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738120/what-does-restore-purchases-in-in-app-purchases-mean?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

[App Store In App Purchases guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase):

> 3.1.1 In-App Purchase:
>
> - If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access
>     to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app
>     purchase. Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or
>     functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR
>     codes, etc. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external
>     links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing
>     mechanisms other than in-app purchase.
> - Apps may use in-app purchase currencies to enable customers to “tip” digital content providers in the app.
> - Any credits or in-game currencies purchased via in-app purchase may not expire, and **you should make sure you have a restore mechanism
>     for any restorable in-app purchases.**
> - Remember to assign the correct purchasability type or your app will be rejected.
> - Apps should not directly or indirectly enable gifting of in-app purchase content, features, or consumable items to others.
> - Apps distributed via the Mac App Store may host plug-ins or extensions that are enabled with mechanisms other than the App Store.
>     Apps offering “loot boxes” or other mechanisms that provide randomized
>     virtual items for purchase must disclose the odds of receiving each
>     type of item to customers prior to purchase.
> - Non-subscription apps may offer a free time-based trial period before presenting a full unlock option by setting up a Non-Consumable
>     IAP item at Price Tier 0 that follows the naming convention: “XX-day
>     Trial.” Prior to the start of the trial, your app must clearly
>     identify its duration, the content or services that will no longer be
>     accessible when the trial ends, and any downstream charges the user
>     would need to pay for full functionality. Learn more about managing
>     content access and the duration of the trial period using Receipts and
>     Device Check.

This line basically means

> if you delete the app, move to a new phone, whatever, your purchases
>   will no longer be available on that device. Restore Purchases asks
>   iTunes what of the available in-app purchases you've paid for.

It does say "should" which you could imply to mean that it is **not forced** but highly suggested.